# Size class issue on ipad and iphon xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uistoryboard, size-classes

I am new to ios development. i am creating the UI Like below image. which is correct exact design what i expect.

[image: iphone]

when i go to ipad, i have used size class for ipad 12.9 inch screen. regular height and regular width. ipad 12.9 inch screen is below.

[image: ipad12.9inch]

it is also looks good. but when i go to ipad pro (9.7inch screen) the text is overlapping on the below image. that is below.

[image: ipad pro 9.7inch]

Same thing happening on ipad 7th generation tablet. that image shown below.

[image: ipad 7th generation]

My question is all ipad is using the same size class. if i change the size class of ipad (hR and wR) it is affecting on all other ipads. i dont want that. how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

All iPads have the same size class which is Regular width and Regular height. More details [here: Section -> Device Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/)

Different positioning probably comes from your auto layout which depends on a device screen size. [Full list here: Section -> Device Screen Sizes and Orientations](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/)